# USB overheats whenever plugged into laptop or mobile phone

Tags: overheating

I've purchased Sandisk ultra pendrive 128gb and when i plugged it in it overheats . Is the heating okay for the laptop's port or should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

It is normal for a flash drive to get warm duing use. (my sandisk cruizer blade gets quite warm when moving files from it)

Heavy file transfers will cause the drive to get warm. This is normal.

But few things you can do:

Run Task Manager to see if there is a lot of drive activity with regard to the USB drives.  (A lot of continual drive activity could cause heat.)  If there isn’t, then the USB port is likely putting out too much power.  I don’t know how that could happen, unless there is a chip in the computer which is bad and which controls power output.

If there is more than one USB port, does the problem happen when you plug the flash drives into a different USB port?

Comment: In case is is not a hardware issue one more thing you can do is reinstall/Update usb driver.If it heats up too much might be a faulty pen drive.